# Can I compete in my own challenge?

Tags: discussion

What are the rules/community consensus about participating in your own challenge?

Does it differ for each of [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) and  [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)?

The person that asks the question isn't the one who picks a winner so...

Comment: I was just wondering about this. I have a bot for [my recent KotH](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/26995/14215) that currently beats all entries. I'm hesitant to enter it, but it's not like designing this challenge gives me a real "edge" on the competition.

Comment: @Geobits On the other hand, especially in KotH challenges posting your own submission might help to get the ball rolling. Also in your case, why not enter it to challenge the participants? ;) You can always exclude it from being declared winner.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, particpating in your own challenge is allowed, no matter of which challenge type. The [Help Center](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says:

> It’s also OK to [participate in your own puzzles](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/self-answer).

But if you participate in your own challenge, it is recommended to wait some time before posting an answer to give others a chance to participate. Please see: [Presolving Golf Questions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/98/9275)

If your own answer is actually the best (according to the objective winning criteria) and you want to accept an answer, it's up to you whether you want to accept your own answer or someone else's answer. Personally, I would accept someone else's answer, but that's personal opinion. Also, accepting your own answer doesn't change very much, because if you accept your own answer, it won't be listed higher in the answer, but accepting someone else's answer does.

Comment: Generally I give a "last-place reference implementation" on my own problems, just to show what an answer to the question I pose should look like. That way, although I "actually participate", my submission can never actually *win*. There was one case where my last-place solution actually [got the most upvotes out of any answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26232/create-a-flood-paint-ai) to the question.