# Why was my challenge not interesting?

Tags: discussion, challenge-quality

In the interest of upping the quality of challenges I may post in the future, I would like to hear your opinions and comments on the challenge I posted two weeks ago:

- [Turn 2D boolean array into (rectilinear) polygons](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1299/turn-2d-boolean-array-into-rectilinear-polygons)

It is clear that there was little to no interest. Only one golfer actually posted a solution. I attempted the challenge myself 8 days later (honestly; I didn’t have a solution up my sleeve already, I actually wrote it just before I posted it) to show that it can be done and that a reasonably short solution is feasible. I continued to improve the solution hoping that it would attract interest in the challenge, but to no avail.

Yet, my challenge seems to fulfill *all* of the criteria given in the accepted answer on this FAQ here:

- [What details should always be given for a code golf task?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93/what-details-should-always-be-given-for-a-code-golf-task)

Now please don’t get me wrong, I am not whining or complaining — quite to the contrary, I would like to find out if there was something the community considered to be wrong with the challenge, so I welcome any constructive criticism, even negative. Thanks!

Comment: For me, it was difficult! I am bad at geometry too. :D

Comment: Maybe it's too time consuming. Personally, I didn't have enough time (and later forgot it).

Comment: I reckoned the rules about when two things join across a diagonal were too strange and likely to suck the fun out of it, so I didn't bother.

Comment: @Eelvex: Why did you estimate this one to be more time-consuming than the others? Personally I actually spent more time on the Koch snowflake and the Suanpan Abacus than this one...

Comment: @Peter Taylor: What exactly about them was strange? Maybe it was just my *description* of it that was strange, but the rule itself is very straight-forward — you will notice that my code has no special case constructs to take care of it, it just flowed naturally.

Comment: @Timwi, the way I ended up understanding that rule is that the topology changes as you toggle the cells.

Comment: Same as others, it looked like a bad fun/time compromise.