# The "How To Ask" page is misleading

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-deferred, asking-questions, help-center

The ["How To Ask"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) page linked from the [Ask Question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) page appears to have been copied wholesale from SO.  It is very Q&A centric:

> We’d love to help you. But not every question on Code Golf gets
>   answered. To improve your chances, here are some tips:
>
> Do your homework.  Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before
>   asking your question?...

Is it possible to update this page to be more in line with this site's charter?  Perhaps it should include text similar to [this CG meta answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/107/152), or [this SO meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/24258/132789).

Comment: Yes, this is a very good point. Really, it should be about searching for similar contests first, and that the contest should be well-written and unambiguous (especially as regards what's required of entrants). As a mod, I don't have the ability to change that page, but staff members can.

Comment: I am marking this as [meta-tag:status-deferred] because this isn't editable by mods and will either require CM work or possibly even dev work, and we have some other more accessible ways to try to clarify our site's scope to new users to prevent off-topic questions.