# How can we improve our help center?

Tags: discussion, help-center

Improving our [Tour](/tour) page and our [help center](/help) pages has been [long in the works](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8351/66833), in particular our [Asking](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/asking) and [Answering](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/answering) pages. Some already existing posts about this are:

- [The "How To Ask" page is misleading](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/477/66833)
- [Can we get a custom Tour page?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8441/66833)
- [Let's rewrite the help center's on-topic page](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2098/66833)
- [A Better Help Center](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2020/66833)

However, those are mostly outdated, and could do with some modernisation. We recently got [confirmation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58925378#58925378) by [Catija](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/78028/catija) (a Community Manager at Stack Exchange) that, if we provided the texts, Stack Exchange is happy to update our [help center](/help).

This leaves us with 2 questions:

- Which pages need updating? and,
- What should those pages say?

This question is intended to address the first question. Please suggest, in answers below, which pages should be changed, and some basic justifications for why they aren't applicable to the site in their current form. Highly voted proposals will be spun out into [separate questions](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58925440#58925440) under the [help-center-rewrite](/questions/tagged/help-center-rewrite) tag, with answers to those questions being drafts for the pages.

Answer (score 2):

### [How do I ask a good question?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

All this information provided is just... wrong. It's vague enough to somewhat apply, but could do with rewording to stick closer to our [How to Ask page](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20862/66833), especially mentioning the Sandbox and our requirement for an [objective winning criteria](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8130/66833).

Answer (score 2):

## [What does it mean when an answer is accepted?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

There is no right answer in [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) questions, which make up 85% of all questions. This page should also explain what acceptance means for non-[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) questions.